# Multi label classification returns mean accuracy of almost 0

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but has in reality > 10000 rows):

```
data = {'age': [54, 21, 7, 18],
        'sex': [0, 1, 1, 0],
        'disease_type': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'F'],
        'change_in_pain': [-0.54, -0.89, 0.07, -0.01],
        'drug': ['drug_1', 'drug_7', 'drug_1', 'drug_89'],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  # the real df has > 10000 rows
```

=>

```
   age  sex disease_type  change_in_pain     drug
0   54    0            A           -0.54   drug_1
1   21    1            B           -0.89   drug_7
2    7    1            A            0.07   drug_1
3   18    0            F           -0.01  drug_89
...
```

I would like to train a model that predicts which drug is most effective for which patient given the patient’s age, sex, disease type and how much the pain was reduced (a more negative “change_in_pain” column is better).

In this simple example “drug_1” woud work for disease A only if the patient is older and female.

I wrote the following code but the mean accuracy is returned as 0.03 :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
   

# shuffle
df = df.sample(frac=1.0).reset_index(drop=True)

X = df[['age', 'sex', 'disease_type', 'change_in_pain']]
y = df['drug']

# convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables.
X_OHE = pd.get_dummies(X)
y_OHE = pd.get_dummies(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_OHE, y_OHE, test_size=0.20)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = knn.score(X_test, y_test)
print('mean accuracy: {:2.2f}'.format(score))
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I tested other classifiers but most (e.g. SVC) crash with:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (4000, 34) instead.
```

(Its a total of 34 drugs)

in line

```
[CLASSIFIER].fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: A link to a representative datasample might be helpful

Comment: Is the error coming from ```y_OHE = pd.get_dummies(y)```?

Comment: I updated where the error is coming from but but knn there is not error anyway - just an avg acc of 0.03

Comment: Remove the two lines with `pd.get_dummies()` , you don't need them for KNeighborsClassifier or SVC.

Comment: if i remove the 2 lines then I get : `could not convert string to float` from `fit` of the scaler as well as the knn ...